# Easiest way to rearrange methods in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor

I am trying to keep functions related to each other close together. What would be the easiest way to rearrange methods within a class in Eclipse?

ALT+UP / ALT+DOWN works for code within methods, but moving the whole function around is a bit hard since it does not respect function boundaries.

Copy/Paste works, but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the outline view you can rearrange methods with the mouse.

Answer (score 4):

In the outline view you can drag and drop methods - you may need to unselect the alphabetic sort option.

Personally, I would not spend too much effort on re-ordering methods. I'd hope that your classes are small enough that it doesn't matter too much, and the outline view helps navigation too.

Comment: Good tip about turning off alphabetic sort, otherwise it will not let you drag.